# How to stretch along X axis with .grid in tkinter python?

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, pack

So I am trying for my program to display the buttons stretched along the window in a certain order and that's why I chose .grid to put them in the screen, I know you can type

```
something.pack(fill=X)
               ^^^^^^
```

to make it stretch along the X axis with .pack but when I try to do the same for .grid it gives me an error, is there another way to do it that's as simple or as close to the one given above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `sticky` parameter for [grid](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm):

```
something.grid(row=0, column=0,sticky='EW')
```

You can use N (north), S, E, W and combinations of them to stick to different corners of the UI.